# Aggregation of Array Contents

Tags: javascript, arrays

## Given

An array of arrays (of differing lengths) of objects

```
const statusLists = [
    [
        { "type": "NEUTRAL" },
        { "type": "GREEN" }
    ],
    [
        { "type": "YELLOW" },
        { "type": "GREEN" },
        { "type": "GREEN" },
        { "type": "NEUTRAL" }
    ],
    [
        { "type": "GREEN" },
        { "type": "RED" },
        { "type": "NEUTRAL" },
        { "type": "GREEN" }
    ]
];
```

Each object containing a specific field with a non-numeric property, e.g. `"NEUTRAL"`, `"GREEN"`, `"YELLOW"`, `"RED"`.

## Challenge

Return a consolidated single array with the "most severe" object for a given index -- identified by its "type" property in a given order (ignoring empty places):

1. `"NEUTRAL"`
2. `"GREEN"`
3. `"YELLOW"`
4. `"RED"`

The output's length is determined by the longest input array in the list.
For the given example above, the following output is expected:

```
[
    { "type": "YELLOW" },
    { "type": "RED" },
    { "type": "GREEN" },
    { "type": "GREEN" }
]
```

## First Approach

```
const worstPerIndex = [];
statusLists.forEach(singleList => singleList.forEach((entry, i) => {
    const currentEntryType = entry[i].type;
    const worstPaymentStatusForPeriod = worstPerIndex[i] ? worstPerIndex[i].type : null;
    switch (worstPaymentStatusForPeriod) {
        case 'GREEN':
            if (currentEntryType === 'YELLOW' || currentEntryType === 'RED') {
                worstPerIndex[i] = entry[i];
            }
            break;
        case 'YELLOW':
            if (currentEntryType === 'RED') {
                worstPerIndex[i] = entry[i];
            }
            break;
        case 'RED':
            break;
        default:
            worstPerIndex[i] = entry[i];
    }
}));
```

---

I cannot shake the feeling that this should be much simpler and shorter.

Comment: This should probably be moved to code review

Comment: what means *"most severe"*?

Comment: By "most severe" I was referring to the best/worst value as per a pre-defined order. In this example, "RED" is more severe/better/worse than all other items, "YELLOW" being second, etc.

Comment: why do you get for index 3 and 4 not the same? GREEN in both cases?

Comment: @NinaScholz you're right. my mistake.

Comment: @zfrisch how could I have generalised this more to make it SO-worthy? This is not my actual code.

Comment: It's not about generalization - in a literal sense you're asking for people to review code, ergo Code Review would probably have been a better place. SO is when you can't find a solution, code review is having people look over your solution to make it better.

Comment: Alright, then we just have different understandings of acceptable solutions. My given approach only works for very small sets of “type” values. I did not deem this to be “a solution” but merely showing that I tried and failed before asking for help. But I should have made that clearer in the question I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably quite simple with reduce:

```
const severity = s => ["NEUTRAL", "GREEN", "YELLOW", "RED"].indexOf(s);

 const result = statusLists.reduce((prev, curr) => {
   // Make sure that we take the longer one
   if(prev.length > curr.length) [prev, curr] = [curr, prev];
   // Join the previous and the current severities and take the more serious ones
   return curr.map((el, i) => severity(prev[i] && prev[i].type) > severity(el.type) ? prev[i] : el);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the maximum index and reduce the arrays.

```js
var statusLists = [[{ type: "NEUTRAL" }, { type: "GREEN" }], [{ type: "YELLOW" }, { type: "GREEN" }, { type: "GREEN" }, { type: "NEUTRAL" }], [{ type: "GREEN" }, { type: "RED" }, { type: "NEUTRAL" }, { type: "GREEN" }]],
    types = ["NEUTRAL", "GREEN", "YELLOW", "RED"],
    typeIndices = Object.assign(...types.map((t, i) => ({ [t]: i }))),
    result = statusLists.reduce((r, a) => {
        a.forEach(({ type }, i) => r[i] = types[Math.max(typeIndices[r[i]] || 0, typeIndices[type])]);
        return r;
    }, [])

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```